# ¿Por qué al hacer un WHILE sobre 2 registros para restar sobre otra tabla, devuelve como si restara 2 veces cada registro?

Tags: php, mysql

**$smtm** recibe el manejador devuelto desde una clase que prepara un procedimiento al trabajar en mysql por PDO.
El SELECT del preprare() consulta sobre una tabla para todos los registros que encuentre que pertenecen al movimiento de ingreso con **$idVoucher**.

**$idbodega** viene dado de más arriba junto con $idVoucher.

Cuando hace la consulta con datos de prueba, tengo la tabla **inventariosbody** con 2 registros que pertenecen al mismo $idVoucher.
El WHILE que se ve más abajo trabaja sobre los dos registros que devuelve el SELECT. De hecho lo comprobé al mostrarlos y corroborar el ->rowCount() que muestra 2. Ahora el campo cantidad del SELECT en el registro tiene el valor 1 para cada registro.

Registros que posee invetariosbody en estos momentos.
[image: registros de la tabla inventariosbody]

La idea que esta rutina debe revertir ese ingreso restando el valor que posee cantidad de la tabla **inventariosbody** del campo stock en dos tablas que controlan el stock de cada producto. Uno es **productos** (maestro de los productos) que lleva el stock total de cada producto y la tabla **stock** que controla el stock de cada producto relacionado a cada bodega (**$idbodega**) que posea la empresa.

Valores actuales en la tabla productos que deberían ser disminuidos su stock
[image: registro de la tabla productos a restar el stock]

Valores actuales en la tabla stock que deberían ser disminuidos su stock
[image: registros de la tabla stock a restar el stock]

Pues bien, como cada registro de la primera tabla "inventariosbody" posee como cantidad 1, el código de más abajo debería restar 1 en la primera iteración del WHILE en las tablas productos y stock para el primer producto que encontró y luego en la segunda iteración, como el segundo producto también en cantidad tiene 1, debería restar 1 y ambos productos en sus stock quedar con 4, pero resulta que termina quedando el stock en ambas tablas con 3 y eso me trae de cabeza.
Se supone que el WHILE debería iterar 2 veces.
Aquí el resultado del campo stock luego de ejecutado el código:

tabla productos luego del código ejecutado.
[image: tabla productos luego del código ejecutado]

tabla stock luego del código ejecutado.

[image: tabla stock luego del código ejecutado]

Código:

```
$smtm = $db->prepare( "SELECT idproducto, descripcion, cantidad FROM inventariosbody WHERE idv=:idVoucher");
$smtm->bindValue(':idVoucher', $idVoucher, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if ($smtm->execute()){
   if ($smtm->rowCount()>0){
      try {
         $db->beginTransaction();
         while ($userRow=$smtm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $db->query("UPDATE productos SET stock=stock-(".$userRow['cantidad'].") WHERE id=".$userRow['idproducto']." LIMIT 1;");
            $db->query("UPDATE stock SET stock=stock-(".$userRow['cantidad'].") WHERE idbodega=".$idbodega." AND idproducto=".$userRow['idproducto']." LIMIT 1");
         }
         $db->commit();
      } catch (Exception $e){
         echo "se ha producido un error y se procede a rollback";
         $db->rollback();
      }
   }
}
```

No entiendo por qué en cada registro resta finalmente 2 y no 1 que sería lo correcto.

Aquí un pantallazo de lo que produce la rutina internamente y se ve que realiza el proceso para los dos productos en 2 tablas diferentes, pero restando solo 1 por producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a sus comentarios y agradecido de la ayuda.

Comment: David, ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Por qué en un while que recorre una sola fila devuelta por el SELECT, debiendo restar el valor 1 que está guardado, resta 2?, como que multiplicara por 2 el valor. Si el valor cantidad es 2 resta finalmente 4. No se si me hago entender, como que el WHILE se repitiera 2 veces donde debe iterar una sola vez.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¡4 consultas dentro de 1 bucle que lee los resultados de otra consulta usando dentro el objeto `$user` que parece ser el resultado mismo que se está leyendo dentro del bucle! El código no es siquiera analizable, ni por ti que lo estás programando y menos por nosotros que no conocemos tu lógica. Te recomiendo que te sientes de nuevo y reflexiones primero sobre qué quieres hacer, y cuando tengas claro lo que quieres hacer, lo intentes de nuevo, de la forma más simple posible y luego escribas el código. Si tienes problemas te ayudaremos, pero el código actual no tiene por donde entrarle.

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario y corrijo ahora arriba el código y la pregunta.